# Cleaning dirty names data in R

Tags: r, duplicates

i have the following problem. I received a list with +10000 Names. The names are grouped and I separated them in a table see below

[image: table of names list]

Look at Line 27, there is different spelling for the same name. Now I want all the "duplicates" removed for each row, but as you can see they are no real duplicates just the spelling is different.

Anybody ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Check out OpenRefine (not in R, but maybe a better tool).

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with, including a representative sample of data